# KSQL : Losing Kstream data after KSQL server restart

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I created a stream using the query "Create stream base_stream with (kafka-topic ="myTopic", format="avro"). This topic has more than 800GB of data and growing.

Questions:

1. Does Kafka duplicate the data from the underlying topic in the new stream? Or it is just the same data?
2. base_stream lost its data when the KSQL server re-started. Is there any way to persist this  data? Because, if the base_stream has to be re-synced/re-created every time KSQL server re-starts, which could take many hours!
3. I know that persistent stream can be created from the "base_stream" , however, we will be duplicating the data in 2 streams

Appreciate your reply, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> I know that persistent stream can be created from the "base_stream" , however, we will be duplicating the data in 2 streams

Storage is cheap. I've seen topics that are many TB large. If you're able to emit aggregate windows over time to reduce size, you can enable compaction as well as retention policies on the topic

> base_stream lost its data when the KSQL server re-started. Is there any way to persist this data?

You created a stream over an existing topic. There's no real data that a stream maintains that needs recovered or is lost, which answers the question 1

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply !  Good to know that a stream dosn't maintain its own data instead uses underlying topic data.  Even a persistent stream doesn't keep its own data? and is it a good idea to create a 'base stream' and immediately create a persistent stream (using select query selecting all data) on this 'base-stream',  so that we can run a query on this any time  instead of waiting for 'base_stream' to re-sync when KSQL server restarts?

Comment: `CREATE STREAM` is a persistent stream, not sure what you mean otherwise. A select query is not persistent. There's nothing to "resync"